# GA4 API - how do I request page path that does NOT start with a string

Tags: php, filter, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am working with a Wordpress site to display the most popular articles from a year ago and am working with Google Analytics 4 API

I have gotten to this point - the snippet filters the pages that start with the the word "category".
How do I filter pages that do NOT start with the word "category"?

```
  'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
        'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
            'value' => '/category',
            'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH
        ])
    ])
])
```

I have tried some REGEX, but I keep getting *Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: { "message": "Unsupported regular expression syntax in value.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `notExpression` in `FilterExpression`. So something like below (I don't know what language your example is in, so i'm guessing  the syntax.) :

```
new FilterExpression([
  'notExpression' => new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
      'field_name' => 'pagePath',
      'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
        'value' => '/category',
        'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH
      ])
    ])
  ])
])
```

I hope this helps.

See [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#:~:text=%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22-,notExpression,-%22%3A%20%7B](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#:%7E:text=%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22-,notExpression,-%22%3A%20%7B)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and finally solved it with the following code:

```
(new FilterExpression())->setNotExpression(new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
        'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
            'value' => '/category',
            'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH,
        ]),
    ]),
]))
```